# Reading material for an introduction to market infrastructure

Tags: markets, books

I often read small one-liners here and there about circuit-breakers or IPO pipeline mechanics, but I have not found a comprehensive guide that unpacks all the moving parts of an exchange or its immediate ecosystem. Particularly interesting would be a quick historical backdrop for some of the major items (i.e. circuit breakers first introduced in 1987 from a crash). Or even a cross-geography comparison (i.e. Chinese exchanges have a maximum trade threshold, preventing the market from extreme up/downturns).

Some market pieces seemed to be for financial stability, others seem to be for efficiency / convenience (i.e. [decimalization](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/decimal-trading.asp)).

### Question

Is there an introductory-level book that has a large focus on market infrastructure / mechanics?

- By "market" I mean equity exchanges, but if that's too specific, we can include tangent industries: In the case of fund management, mechanisms like side-pocket accounts and fund gating come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Trading and Exchanges: Market Microstructure for Practitioners*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1290158.Trading_and_Exchanges) by Larry Harris is a good place to start.

Worth noting its a fast moving and reflexive environment so lots of the best books on this type of stuff become dated quickly - requires a blend of this type of reading alongside checking latest exchange rules/changes etc.

Comment: *Trading and Electronic Markets: What Investment Professionals Need to Know* is another book by Larry Harris. It is available for free at the CFA Institute's website.